# changing an uncontrolled input in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple react component with the table which I add row and delete row dynamically in table but when I change or type a text in input I got error:(
When I run my application I get the following warning:
A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled. Input elements should not switch........

Also in react tools, state shows rows as array thats ok when I type first cell its update it then wanna type second cell first one disappear :(

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    rows: [{}]
  }
  handleChange = idx => e => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const rows = [...this.state.rows];
    rows[idx] = {
      [name]: value
    };
    this.setState({
      rows
    });
  };
  handleAddRow = () => {
    const item = {
      columnName: "",
      dataType: "",
      values: ""
    };
    this.setState({
      rows: [...this.state.rows, item]
    });
  };
  handleRemoveRow = () => {
    this.setState({
      rows: this.state.rows.slice(0, -1)
    });
  };
  handleRemoveSpecificRow = (idx) => () => {
    const rows = [...this.state.rows]
    rows.splice(idx, 1)
    this.setState({ rows })
  }


 <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th className="text-center"> # </th>
                    <th className="text-center"> Column Name </th>
                    <th className="text-center"> DataType </th>
                    <th className="text-center"> Values </th>

                    <th />
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  {this.state.rows.map((item, idx) => (
                    <tr id="addr0" key={idx}>
                      <td>{idx}</td>
                      <td>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          name="columnName"
                          value={this.state.rows[idx].columnName}
                          onChange={this.handleChange(idx)}
                          className="form-control"
                        />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          name="dataType"
                          value={this.state.rows[idx].dataType}
                          onChange={this.handleChange(idx)}
                          className="form-control"
                        />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          name="values"
                          value={this.state.rows[idx].values}
                          onChange={this.handleChange(idx)}
                          className="form-control"
                        />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <button
                          className="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm"
                          onClick={this.handleRemoveSpecificRow(idx)}
                        >
                          Sil
                        </button>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  ))}
                </tbody>
```

Comment: reason is, initial value of `this.state.rows[idx].columnName` will be `undefined` thats why. so either use it like this: `value={this.state.rows[idx].columnName || ''}` or define `columnName: ''` in the state array.

Comment: thats worked bro thanks what about state changing I fiil up all cells of row but last one I enter the value only appear on console. 0:
values: "asd"
__proto__: Object
1:
dataType: "sd"
__proto__: Object
length: 2

Comment: can you explain more, value is not reflecting in input element?

Comment: Its ok brother I have done it.